# Get value in variable

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language

[image: code]

Hi, I'm pretty new to gamemaker and I'm trying to set a variable (global.b1) to the first value of "global.level_data". For example, global.b1 will be set to mimic the blue outline of "global.level_data"'s first value, which is 0. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at it correctly, you want to get the first value of an array

I think this should suffice:

```
 global.level_data = [0,0]
 global.b1 = global.level_data[0];
```

It may look confusing if you're not familiar with how arrays work, but the `[0]` represents the first value of the array (which happens to be 0 as well). The count of arrays also starts with 0 instead of 1.

For further understanding about arrays, I recommend reading this: https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Overview/Arrays.htm

And as a side note: if you're creating new variables, the values in that variable will usually not update it's original form (e.g. changing the value `global.b1` will not change the value in `global.level_data[0]` unless you set that yourself).

If you prefer the latter, then I think you're better off using `global.level_data[0]` for getting and setting directly